# Submitting partial view is failing

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have been trying to implement this cascading drop down for hours following this tutorial with no luck: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/258172/Simple-Implementation-of-MVC-Cascading-Ajax-Drop-D.
The issue is not with my controller nor with the jquery event that fires when my dropdown list is changed. I am assuming the issue lies with the line `$(this).parents('form').submit();`

Here is the view where my problem is occurring

```
@model gcaMusicExchange.ViewModels.CategoryResultsViewModel
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SelectMake", "PerformancePartResults", new AjaxOptions {
         UpdateTargetId = "ModelControl" }))
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(P => P.SelectedMake, new SelectList(Model.Makes, "id", "Name", ""))
}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#SelectedMake').change(function () {
    $(this).parents('form').submit();
});
```

And here is the actionresult

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SelectMake(int SelectedMake)
    {
        if (SelectedMake != -1)
        {
            using (var context = new JDMExchangeEntities())
            {
                List<VehicleModel> models = context.VehicleModels.Where(p => p.MakeId == SelectedMake).ToList();

                SelectList selectModels = new SelectList(models);

                return PartialView("ModelsUserControl", selectModels);
            }
        }

        ViewModels.CategoryResultsViewModel vM = new ViewModels.CategoryResultsViewModel();
        vM.SelectedMake = (int)SelectedMake;

        return View(vM);
    }
```

If I set a break point on the action result it never gets executed.

Comment: have you included all the necessary scrips?

Comment: I spaced! I had everything in my layout except the jquery min file *face palm*